# Como introduzir codigo HTML em PHP

Tags: php, html, css

tenho o seguinte codigo PHP:

```
<?php

    include("config.php");

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            echo "you are not logged in,please click here to <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>";
        } else{

     $query = $_GET['query']; 


        $min_length = 3;


        if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

            $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


            $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);

          $row_results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM books WHERE `Title` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `category` LIKE '%".$query."%'OR `category` LIKE '%".$query."%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));


            if(mysqli_num_rows($row_results) > 0){ 

                while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($row_results)){

                    echo "<span>".$results['Title']."</span>"
                        "</h3>".$results['category']."</p>";

                }
            }
            else{ 
                echo "No results";
            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
        }
        }
    ?>
```

E no `echo` quero personalizar utilizando HTML e CSS. a minha pergunta e como introduzir codigo HTML em PHP?

Comment: Você já faz isso ali: `echo "<span>".$results['Title']."</span>"` (aliás, falta um `.` no final desta linha para concatenar com a próxima *string*). E aqui: `"</h3>".$results['category']."</p>";` você está fechando um elemento `h3` e um `p` que não fazem muito sentido.

Comment: nao esta a funcionar podemos falar no chat sff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além das outras respostas, que estão corretas, você pode usar o `include`com o **php**.

```
        ...
        if(mysqli_num_rows($row_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($row_results)){

                echo "<span>".$results['Title']."</span>"
                    "</h3>".$results['category']."</p>";

            }
        }
        else{ 
            include("erro_no_found.html"); // coloquei aqui para exemplificar
        }
        ...
```

Logo abaixo a página erro **(erro_no_found.html)**:

```
<h1>Não encontramos resultados para a sua pesquisa</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

basta você colocar no echo mesmo

```
echo "<head>";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mystyle.css'>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<a class='classeexemplo'>TEXTO COM EFEITO CSS</a>";
```

mas também é possível fazer a pagina em html e só usar o código php em lugares específicos

```
<table>
 <?php gerarTabela(); ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias formas de no `echo` personalizar utilizando HTML e CSS

Exemplos:

1 - diretamente no próprio arquivo

```
<head>
   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='estilo.css'>
</head>

<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
         echo "<span class='notLogged' you are not logged in,please click here to</span> <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>";

    } else{
     ............
```

**estilo.css**

```
 a {
   text-decoration : none;
   .........
 } 
 .notLogged {
   ........
 }
```

2 - com include

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    //pagina em html
    include("not_logged.html");
} else{
 ............
```

**config.php**

```
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='estilo.css'>";
```

**not_logged.htm**

```
 <span class='notLogged' you are not logged in,please click here to</span> <a href='memberarea.html'>Login</a>
```